# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/util/ISO8601DateFormat

Tags: java, json, spring, jersey, stormpath

I am using Stormpath and I am trying to register a user. I have not done any JVM configuration, all my configurations are default ones.

One I try to register the user this is the error that I get:

```
Nov 27, 2014 12:05:17 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
    SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/util/ISO8601DateFormat
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3067)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1817)
        at com.stormpath.sdk.lang.Classes.getConstructor(Classes.java:179)
        at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultResourceFactory.instantiate(DefaultResourceFactory.java:59)
        at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.getResource(DefaultDataStore.java:207)
        at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.getResource(DefaultDataStore.java:174)
        at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.client.DefaultClient.getCurrentTenant(DefaultClient.java:105)
        at com.wemode.rest.api.UserApi.registerUser(UserApi.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.util.ISO8601DateFormat
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        ... 51 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the error,first impression it gives is that maybe the Jackson jar is missing or it is not able to find it

Comment: I have these dependencies related to jakson:

`        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not  mapped jakson or not added jakson if added u want to add jakson in jersey "POJOMappingFeature" ..just check this web.xml

```
    <web-app >

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: This is my conf:

`<servlet>
 <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.wemode.rest.api</param-value>
 </init-param>

 <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>

 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>`

PS:Sorry I cannot format it :(